# How to define translations for text inserted by a custom command?

Tags: xetex, languages, polyglossia

How would I go about having the output of a custom command depend on the language chosen (e.g. insert "Example" in English, "Exemple" in French and "Beispiel" in German)? I'm using XeTeX with `polyglossia`, but it would of course be even nicer to have a solution that would work with `babel` as well.

Comment: Maybe have a look https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116817 the presented solutions should work for both `polyglossia` and `babel`

Answer (score 0):

There's a package for this, named [translations](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/translations?lang=en), funnily enough.

Thanks clemens for pointing me to [Translation of words according to babel language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116817/translation-of-words-according-to-babel-language) .